# Dynamic type hints derived from python dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, python-typing

In the code below, how can I have `my_dict_keys_type` and `my_dict_values_type` without manually update it every time the dictionary change?

```py
my_dict = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": "2",
  "c": True
}
my_dict_keys_type = Union[Literal["a"], Literal["b"], Literal["c"]]
my_dict_values_type = Union[int, str, bool]

def get(key: my_dict_keys_type) -> my_dict_values_type:
  return my_dict[key]
```

I need to have the IDE type checking it, perhaps there is a way to use a generic type?

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically change the signature of the function when the dictionary is independently updated? Maybe give an example of a change and what you would like to be updated as a result.

Comment: For the given use-case, it looks like you should be using a [``TypedDict``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) and forget about *dynamically* constructing *static* types.